# Change Twitter followers for reputation

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools

I have some twitter followers that i don't want any longer. 
I have been using them for a while but at this point i dont feel like feeding them up with silly twits, so im considering getting rid of them.

I wonder if that can be used to buy SE reputation, or to be attached to my questions as a bounty.

They are polite, clean, and good-dressers

Answer (score 9):

Can I have them?

[image]